# Volusion template editing .asp code to include additional header graphic

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp-classic, volusion

I hope someone can help as .asp is new to me and this is giving me a lot of head scratching!

Basically we have an ecommerce Volusion template, in the header we'd like to add a new graphic next to one that already exists, should be easy but some .asp code seems to be hiding elements in the header. I try to explain in the code:

**ASP**

```
    $("#content_area").find("table:contains('Home >')").css("display",     "none").html("");

   var a = $(".productnamecolorLARGE").html();
   if (document.location.href.indexOf("help")  == -1) {
      if ($(".productnamecolorLARGE").html() != 'Order Status') {
         if ($.browser.msie) {
            $(".productnamecolorLARGE").html("<tr><td></td><td width='490'><div  style='font-size: 21px; margin-bottom: -2px; padding-top: 19px;'>" + a + "</div></td></tr>");
         } else {
            $(".productnamecolorLARGE").html("<tr><td></td><td width='490'><div style='font-size: 21px; margin-bottom: -25px; padding-top: 19px;'>" + a + "</div></td></tr>");
         }
      };
    } else {
     $("#content_area").find("img").eq(0).remove();
   }

   $("#lnk1").css("color","#79496a");
        $("#Header_ProductDetail_ProductDetails_span").parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().remove();
   $("#headerTop").find("a").eq(0).html("<ing border=0 src='/v/vspfiles/templates/192/images/view_bag_small.png'>");
   $(".video_container").css("padding", "17px 10px 16px 45px");
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="header" style="z-index: 999;">
<div id="display_homepage_title"><a href="http://www.domain.com/default.asp" title="www.domain.com">www.domain.com</a></div>

<div id="headerTop">
   <a href="http://www.domain.com/shoppingcart.asp">View Bag</a>
   <a href="http://www.domain.com/aboutus.asp">About</a> 
   <a href="http://www.domain.com/myaccount.asp">My Account</a>
```

This is what I am trying to do:

```
<div id="headerTop">
   <!-- This line is being added --> <a href="http://www.domain.com/returns.asp"><ing src="newgrahpic.jpg" width="100" height-"50"></a>
   <a href="http://www.domain.com/shoppingcart.asp">View Bag</a>
   <a href="http://www.domain.com/aboutus.asp">About</a> 
   <a href="http://www.domain.com/myaccount.asp">My Account</a>
```

When making this change the .asp seems to be adding the existing View bag graphic (line 2) against my new (line 1)  and then displays "My Account" to the right of it, whereas My account is hidden with the Display:none; assigned to it before I add the new line.

I appreciate this may sound like a load of nonsense but I hope someone can make some sense of what its doing?!

Thanks in advance for any help.

Rich

Comment: The code you have posted looks like client side javascript not ASP code.

Comment: In `$("#headerTop").find("a").eq(0).html("<ing border=0 src='/v/vspfiles/templates/192/images/view_bag_small.png'>");`, did you see you wrote "ing" instead of "img" ?

Comment: Do you have a link (I know this question is quite old)? Like @Shikiryu said, the img is actually spelled ing in your code. Also, how are you hiding the 'My Account' link with display:none? I don't see an ID or class selector on it for it to reference the CSS.

Comment: This would be possible doing some custom-coding (javascript) on the client-side. We have done a couple of sites this way and works alright.

In your case, the first code you're showing is not ASP, but client-side JavaScript (jQuery library). All that can be achieved by creating your own code over their template.

Answer (score 1):

Actually it’s impossible :( sorry to disappoint you. Volusion claims to have simple to use structure, but any changes made to template will not work. Only CSS changes work (due to their weird CMS ASP engine that seems to re-write our custom codes). Here is an article that shares in-depth look at complexity of volusion’s templates: http://tech-hive.com/reviews/shopping-carts/volusion-every-themers-nightmare-20100615/#

The real question, is there any other reputable provider that has CML that would allow us to do custom coding? And that’s the question I seek answer to.

Comment: 3dcart will allow you to change any and all code in the template. The dashboard is not as user friendly as Volusion but for a site that needs a lot of custom code, it works great.